# In rails, Generating a language hash using localization, how to cache?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Using the locales yml files, I want to pre-generate a javascript hash that contains key/value pairs that I will use in my javascript files when displaying messages in the UI.

How can I generate this hash file so I can do:

```
lang["must_be_logged_in"]
```

and it will output:

```
"Sorry, you have to login first"
```

So when a user visites the page, I will lookup the local they want, and then in my application.html.erb file I will inject the javascript hash of all language key/value pairs that my other .js files will be referencing.

Answer (score 1):

Use [i18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860660/rails-i18n-and-routes-in-javascript/2862742#2862742) for more details.